# URL Redirection if only certain URL is matched htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I have a very small and odd issue. I want to write a rule which allows me to redirect URL.

```
https://www.example.com/category/florists/
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/category/florists.html
```

but to keep in mind there are other URLs which will be made from the above like

```
https://www.example.com/category/florists/fl/miami.html
```

I wrote a rule in `.htaccess` but it is causing trouble to later URLs

```
Redirect 302 "/category/florists/" /category/florists.html
```

this rule works fine but for this URL
`https://www.example.com/category/florists/fl/miami.html`

it makes it like this

```
https://www.example.com/category/florists.html/fl/miami.html
```

how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive uses simple prefix-matching and everything after the match is copied into the end of the target URL (which explains your undesirable and malformed additional redirects).

To match just that one URL you need to use a `RedirectMatch` directive instead which matches against a regular expression (not prefix-matching).

For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/category/florists/$ /category/florists.html
```